# How to publish binary Python wheels for linux on a local machine

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel

I have a package containing C extensions that I would like to upload to pypi: https://github.com/Erotemic/netharn

I built a wheel on Ubuntu 18.04 using the command `python setup.py bdist_wheel --py-limited-api=cp36`, but when I went to upload with `twine upload --skip-existing dist/*`, but then I get the error that it has an unsupported platform tag:

```
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Binary wheel 'netharn-0.0.4-cp36-abi3-linux_x86_64.whl' has an unsupported platform tag 'linux_x86_64'. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

After a bit of searching I found that PEP 513 requires building a wheel to support manylinux (aka Centos5): https://github.com/pypa/manylinux

They provide an example here: https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo/blob/master/travis/build-wheels.sh

However, all examples I can find always build their binaries using some sort of CI server. If possible I would like to be able to build them locally. I thought that it should be simple to just replicate the docker commands and built it in a docker container on my own machine. However, I'm having issues.  (I ensured any existing build and dist directories in the repo were removed)

The first thing I did was to dump myself in an interactive docker session so I could play with things. I chose the x8_64 image and mounted the local directory to my code repository on `/io` in the docker machine. I then started an interactive bash session.

```
REPO_DPATH=$HOME/code/netharn
DOCKER_IMAGE=quay.io/pypa/manylinux1_x86_64
PRE_CMD=""
# Interactive test
docker run -it --rm -v $REPO_DPATH:/io $DOCKER_IMAGE $PRE_CMD bash
```

Inside docker, I first wanted to build a wheel for python36 (really this is the only Python I'm interested in supporting at the moment).

```
PYBIN=/opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/
```

Simply installing my requirements.txt didn't seem to work, so I manually installed a few packages first. After doing that (`imgaug` was the culprit because it relies on a specific master build), installing requirements.txt seemed to work.

```
    cd /io
    "${PYBIN}/pip" install opencv_python
    "${PYBIN}/pip" install Cython
    "${PYBIN}/pip" install pytest
    "${PYBIN}/pip" install -e git+https://github.com/aleju/imgaug.git@master#egg=imgaug
    "${PYBIN}/pip" install torch  # this is in the requirements.txt, but will cause problems later
    "${PYBIN}/pip" install -r requirements.txt
```

I then run the wheel command and bundle external shared libraries into wheels

```
"${PYBIN}/pip" wheel /io/ -w wheelhouse/
for whl in wheelhouse/*.whl; do
    auditwheel repair "$whl" -w /io/wheelhouse/
done
```

The last step is to install the package and test

```
    "${PYBIN}/pip" install netharn --no-index -f /io/wheelhouse

    (cd "$HOME"; "${PYBIN}/python" -m xdoctest netharn all)
```

However, when I got to test it I get

```
ImportError: /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: ELF file OS ABI invalid
```

I guess this is because `torch` does not support Centos5.
What I don't get is how `torch` gets away with uploading a `cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` shared library to pypi, but I'm having issues?

Comment: `torch` didn't upload `cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, they [uploaded](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files)  manylinux1_x86_64 binary wheels.

Comment: Why do I have `_C.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` in my site packages and when I try `pip install torch -U` it says `Requirement already up-to-date: torch in /home/joncrall/venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.4.0)`? I haven't built torch from source on this machine, so why is pip giving me a `cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` binary?

Comment: Because this .so is in a manylinux1_x86_64.whl.

Comment: a little late, but torch at one point (maybe still) was uploading wheels that they _manually tagged as manylinux despite not being manylinux_ -- this is how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on this, the modern (as of 2023) way to accomplish this is to use cibuildwheel: https://cibuildwheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

This works well both locally and on CI instances. I have several projects that use this method for building, testing, and publishing binary wheels.

https://gitlab.kitware.com/computer-vision/kwimage_ext

https://github.com/Erotemic/vtool_ibeis_ext

https://github.com/Erotemic/pyflann_ibeis

https://github.com/Erotemic/pyhesaff

https://github.com/Erotemic/networkx_algo_common_subtree

These all use CMake + scikit-build to define how to build binaries, and then cibuildwheel takes care of the rest with minimal configuration in pyproject.toml

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works **with caveats explained below**.

```
pip install auditwheel twine
apt install patchelf
```

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
auditwheel repair [[lib]]-linux_x86_64.whl -w . --plat manylinux_2_24_x86_64
twine upload [[lib]]-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl
```

#### Context

I have a C library w/ python wrapper I don't own directly (making CI difficult) with a very small user base (don't need true manylinux support) and an official conda binary that doesn't include the wrapper (don't want to make a competing conda channel).

The above solves my specific needs on Ubuntu 20.04 but please read below before using.

#### Caveats

- If you have control of your repo, you really should be using CI. If this is set up, then there's no need for command-line uploads.
- This doesn't support the older/broader `manylinux_1` distro as [Ubuntu 20.04 is too new for it](https://github.com/pypa/auditwheel/issues/291). This should still support the bulk of Linux distros but might not run on older hardware (ex. university HPC clusters).
- It would likely be better to build directly from a docker container. The build + repair workflow is ugly. I'm guessing this is not much more than a file rename with some .so cleanup.